# Regenerate a table right after a computed property was accessed

Tags: vue.js

I have the following problem. I need to regenerate a table every time a `sqlData()` computed property is accessed.

```html
<div v-for="(val, key) in table">
<!-- display table data -->
</div>
```

```js
computed: {
  sqlData () {
  // read SQL with axios
  return this.table = response.data
  }
},
methods: {
  methodOne() {
   // make some changes to the SQL, then call to read the updated table
   this.sqlData;
 },
  methodTwo() {
  // make some other changes to the SQL, then call to read the updated table
   this.sqlData;
 }
}
```

Could you suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to make `vue.js` reload a component by updating the `key`-attribute (which is good practice to set when using `v-for`, anyway).

So, in your case, you could have a counter as key:

```html
<div v-for="(val, key) in table" :key="counter + key">
<!-- display table data -->
</div>
```

```js
data: {
  counter: 0
},
computed: {
  sqlData () {
  // read SQL with axios
  return this.table = response.data
  }
},
methods: {
  methodOne() {
   // make some changes to the SQL, then call to read the updated table

  counter++
   this.sqlData;
 },
  methodTwo() {
  // make some other changes to the SQL, then call to read the updated table

  counter++

   this.sqlData;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Although, as Rohìt Jíndal mentioned, a computed property is indeed not needed and the SQL query is better used as a method.

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement, computed property is not `required`. Initially on component load you can update the table content in the `mounted()` life cycle hook.

You can use this approach **:**

```
mounted() {
   this.getTableData();
},
methods: {
  getTableData() {
    // read SQL with axios
    this.table = response.data;
  },
  methodOne() {
   // make some changes to the SQL, then call to read the updated table
   this.getTableData();
 },
  methodTwo() {
  // make some other changes to the SQL, then call to read the updated table
   this.getTableData();
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Rohìt! You are right, the SQL query is better used in a method.

Comment: @display_name Thanks, Kindly do accept if it helps you to work in a right direction. So that it will be helpful for other fellow developers as well